# Add static const data to a struct already defined

Tags: c++

Since static const data inside a class is really just namespace sugar for constants I would think that

```
struct A {
    float a;

    struct B {
       static const int b = 2;
    };

 };
```

would be equivalent to

```
struct A {
    float a;
};

struct A::B {
    static const int b = 2;
};
```

or something similar.  Is something like this possible in C++?  It would be useful for me to be able to tag class definitions that I'm pulling in from third party libraries with information like this.

Comment: What are your concrete requirements? The first block is equivalent to `struct A { float a; struct B; }; struct A::B { static const int b = 2; };`

Answer (score 3):

You can't reopen struct/class definitions in C++, so the best you can do is create derived versions of the third party structs and add your constants that way:

```
struct My_A : public A 
{
    static const int b = a;
};
```

Otherwise, you could maintain a map of your constants with keys based on struct typeid.

I do like Georg's idea as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't just redefine classes that way.

If you want to tag already defined classes, you could do that non-intrusively using e.g. template specializations:

```
template<class T> struct tagged;

template<> struct tagged<A> {
    static const int b = 42;
};
```